# About Spark's persistence mechanism

Tags: java, apache-spark, caching, bigdata

I am facing a weird problem related to spark's persistence mechanism. I am trying to persist a fairly big Dataset (MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER) with the following spark (2.1.1) configuration :

> --num-executors 27 
>   --executor-memory 30GB 
>   --executor-cores 5

- The cluster I'm running the spark app on has the following characteristics :

> Numbers of nodes : 9, Memory per node : 100GB, Core per node : 15

- The Dataset has :

> 810 partitions (27*5*6)

The dataset reaches a 1.4TB size in memory, which explains why I'm using MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER persistence. However, at some point, when 15G (30*0.5) per node are fully used for memory persistence, instead of writing into disk, Spark executors fail and so does the spark program.
Did anyone ever face this kind of problem ? Could anyone suggest an alternative solution ?
I absolutely need to persist my datasets because recomputing them is very (very!) expensive.

---

On a similar note, I have a question about persistence order. Let's assume, my code is as follows :

```
Dataset<T> mydataset = loading a file;
mydataset.map(...).persist().count();
Dataset<T> mydataset2 = mydataset.map(...);
mydataset.unpersist();
mydataset2.persist().count();
```

I understand that persist is a lazy operation. If I break down the code, what I would assume is that mydataset will be computed and persisted, then, mydataset2 will use mydataset (which is persisted) for computations. Mydataset is unpersisted right away and replaced with mydataset2 in memory storage. Right ?
Well what I have noticed on SparkUI is that mydataset is unpersisted way before mydataset2 is computed. Is this the expected behavior or am I missing something ?

Thanks.

Comment: I believe that it's a XY problem. I suggest that you create an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Maybe Spark is failing for a completly different reason (memory leak whether in your code or in spark's, etc.) It's hard to tell with the given information.

Comment: Eliasah, to be more precise, here is the exception raised when I am using MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER : 
ExecutorLostFailure (executor 7 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Container killed by YARN for exceeding memory limits. 22.8 GB of 22 GB physical memory used. Consider boosting spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead.
The problem is that I find it very odd spark is trying to persist a block to memory when he is not supposed to do so. Why isn't he persisting to disk when no more memory is available ?

Comment: Seems to make sense to me. Nothing 'happens' with regard to mydataset2 until an action is called - in your example this is not until the last line. mydataset.unpersist() is called before this. Looking here: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.scala strongly suggests that your unpersist call will block until complete:  def unpersist(blocking: Boolean = true)

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion would be (if you have the option) to just write the dataset to HDFS you're currently trying to persist, and then read it back in. Keeps it simple! I've found all sorts of weird issues with caching/persisting in the past and normally conclude that the slightly longer runtime is more than worth my time getting persisting working; this is especially going to be true if it's expensive making the dataset in the first place.

Comment: Isn't this the behavior of DISK_ONLY storageLevel ? I can probably try to dot this. As far as writing directly to the disk, my dataset has complex types in it (Mostly Hashmaps), I will need to apply a flatmap on it and then write it. This operation would too expensive in my opinion. I will end up with a factor of *1000 in terms size.

Comment: My understanding is DISK_ONLY will cause executors to 'save' the data to their local disk. The lineage of the dataset will be kept the same. Writing to HDFS and reading back in would truncate the lineage and allow you to use the intermediary dataset in separate jobs.

Comment: Ok, I understand now. This is quite similar to checkpoint, which truncates lineage as well.

Comment: That's why I said that it's XY problem